# calculating truncated triangular distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

In a software I am using, I can use a random generator to estimate the mean value and standard error of the variable; I know the variable has more likely a triangular distribution but only I can specify uniform and normal distribution for random number generator.
To estimate a truncated triangular distribution at zero for my variable (regarding it can't get negative sign), would it be correct if I use uniform draw as follows?

TRIANGULAR = (RND1_Uniform[0,1],RND2_Uniform[0,1])/2

Comment: what do you mean by (truncated) *triangular* distribution ? there are many *triangles* that can be hypothesized, and truncated where ? can you draw a sketch of the distribution ?

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a unit square with area = 1.  Draw a diagonal line from upper left corner (0,1) to lower-right corner (1,0) of the square.  This gives you two triangles.  Now (in your mind) take the upper-right triangle and fold it over the diagonal line so that it overlays the lower-left triangle.  This gives you a half-triangular distribution.

Now, select a random x from 0 to 1 and a random y from 0 to 1.  If x+y < 1 then the point can be plotted on the lower-left triangle.  Your function returns x.  But if x+y > 1, then the point would fall on the folded-over upper-right triangle.  You need to transform the values as follows:

new x = (1-y)  new y = (1-x)

and your function returns your new x.